# Convert BMP to WSQ format in python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fingerprint, bmp

I am trying to convert fingerprint bmp image to wsq image using Python.I have to do it in runtime and integrate it with my other code.How can i do it? Thanks

Comment: Did you check [this library](https://pypi.org/project/wsq/)?

Comment: @gimix Thanks for your comment.  Yes Did. Cant understand what is the parameter for encode(Encode Function in this library) for runtime conversion.